# How to push object into array by checking it is undefined or not in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, undefined

I want to push object into array if it is defined else push '0'

I am sending count object into count array.

```js
var emptyObj = { 'cnt': 0 };

countArr.push(matchCdnCnt !== 'undefined' ? matchCdnCnt : emptyObj.cnt);
countArr.push(matchInvCnt !== 'undefined' ? matchInvCnt : emptyObj.cnt);
countArr.push(mismatchInvCnt !== 'undefined' ? mismatchInvCnt : emptyObj.cnt);
countArr.push(mismatchCdnCnt !== 'undefined' ? mismatchCdnCnt : emptyObj.cnt);
countArr.push(onHoldInvCnt !== 'undefined' ? onHoldInvCnt : emptyObj.cnt);
countArr.push(onHoldCdnCnt !== 'undefined' ? onHoldCdnCnt : emptyObj.cnt);
countArr.push(availgstnInvCnt !== 'undefined' ? availgstnInvCnt : emptyObj.cnt);
countArr.push(availgstnCdnCnt !== 'undefined' ? availgstnCdnCnt : emptyObj.cnt);
countArr.push(pendingInvCnt !== 'undefined' ? pendingInvCnt : emptyObj.cnt);
countArr.push(pendingCdnCnt !== 'undefined' ? pendingCdnCnt : emptyObj.cnt);
```

I wants to push count object or 0.

Comment: `'undefined'` and `undefined` are not the same.

Comment: you can use `countArr.push(matchCdnCnt  || emptyObj.cnt)`

Comment: @AZ_ And what if value is some other falsy value ?

Comment: ahh missed that, thanks @prsvr. will have to use ternary.

Answer (score 1):

You achieve this with only one condition `if(cnt)`, Check below snippet, I take an array of `objects` to check all cases In which It pushes 0 into an `array` if `cnt` is `undefined`/`''`/`null` else it's push value of `cnt`.

```js
const array = [];
const myObjects = [{ cnt: 3 }, { cnt: 4 }, { cnt: 5 }, { cnt: undefined }, { cnt: '' }, { cnt: null }];

myObjects.forEach((m) => {
  const { cnt } = m;
  const pushElement = cnt || 0;
  array.push(pushElement);
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
let emptyObj = { 'cnt': 3 };
let undefinedObj;

let array = [
  emptyObj && emptyObj.cnt ? emptyObj.cnt : 0,
  undefinedObj ? undefinedObj: 0
];

console.log(array)
```

The `emptyObj && emptyObj.cnt ? emptyObj.cnt : 0` doesn't only validates "undefined" objects but also nulls objects.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution where it will assign count 0 if required count variable return undefined else cnt value as below

```
    countArr.push(typeof matchCdnCnt!= 'undefined'? matchCdnCnt.cnt: emptyObj.cnt);
    countArr.push(typeof matchInvCnt!= 'undefined'? matchInvCnt.cnt: emptyObj.cnt);
```

I have to do so much after this result.